# Check if we are internet connection is online using C++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, connection

Previously I used SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress() function on Mac OS to check if we are online. For Windows I used "connect.dll" library and it's method - IsInternetConnected(), but I could not find any solution for C++ in Linux, I want good solution that will work on any linux, please advice are there some analogs of that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe send DNS requests with c-ares library (or some other DNS library) for some host (e.g. google.com).